# Insert trigger on Account creates new case and After Trigger on Case failed to Update case

Tags: trigger

I have  created after insert trigger on Account which creates a new case when an account is created, I have  created another after trigger on case and I am trying to update the field value or set any field in the case. While trying so I am getting the error:

> Error: Invalid Data. Review all error messages below to
>   correct your data. Apex trigger AccountTrigger caused an unexpected
>   exception, contact your administrator: AccountTrigger: execution of
>   AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First
>   exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
>   caseTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
>   System.FinalException: Record is read-only Trigger.caseTrigger: line
>   4, column 1: []: Trigger.AccountTrigger: line 7, column 1.

Can u please let me know the reason ! Thanking in Advance

Trigger on Account:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on  Account(after insert) {
    for (Account cc : trigger.new){
        Case contactCase = new Case();
        contactCase.priority = 'Ultra High';
        contactCase.subject = 'Send them a free T shirt';
        contactCase.AccountId= cc.id;
        insert contactCase;
    }
}
```

Trigger on Case:

```
trigger caseTrigger on Case (after insert) {
    for ( Case c :  Trigger.new){
        if (c.SuppliedCompany== NULL){
        c.SuppliedCompany ='this is my new company';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger on `Case` should be `before insert` not `after insert`. You can not update records in an after trigger.

Comment: Thanks Bravo !!! I was confused whether we can perform update in after triggers .. You are right we can only update records in before triggers . But is there anyway to update a record after the record is inserted having after trigger associated with the inserted record !!

Answer (score 0):

You can not use an after update trigger to update the same object again. This could potentially create an infinite trigger loop.

Try switching to a before update trigger to make the required change.

You can Refer :- https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm